# Daily summary reports of ec2 instances and s3 usage

Tags: scripting, amazon-ec2, report

I want to script a daily report of all EC2 usage and send the summary to my stakeholders. Are there systems already in place to do this or has someone already built a script for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to my knowledge to write a script to do this. I would consider using cloud management softwares. They provide monitoring tools to track EC2/S3 usage, offering either their custom tools or integrating Amazon CloudWatch. **Ylastic** and **RightScale** are two of them, but you can check out as well **[Scalr](http://scalr.net)** (disclaimer: I work there) or **enStratus**. Alerts and notifications (via email or SMS) are currently on our [roadmap](http://wiki.scalr.net/Roadmap).

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question, which is asking for a custom script (command line ?) to collect EC2 usage

Comment: You are right but my point was to say there is no easy way to my knowledge to do this. That's why I suggested a cloud management software as it's a problem they usually solve. I'm gonna tweak my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

At the most basic level that most users of EC2 experience, the answer is no.  However, Amazon developed [DevPay](http://aws.amazon.com/devpay/) to support all of the billing infrastructure.

You may find it easier to adapt to DevPay as it records all of the itemized & aggregate usage, so that you can avoid dealing with why your #s may not match up with AWS's.

Keep in mind that although the DevPay site describes billing your clients, you can set up accounts and act as the middle-man for accounting, if you would prefer not to set up EC2 utilization for your clients.  This consideration depends on whether or not you are doing the computation or they are.

Other options for such services are:

- Cloudrows.com
- Ylastic
- RightScale

Update 1: If you are looking for other metrics of usage than price information, [Amazon's CloudWatch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) may be the answer.